# Determine if path is inside another path in Go

Tags: file, go, path

I would like to delete all path components for a file up to (but not including) an overall base directory.

Example:
/overall/basedir/a/b/c/file

I want to remove "file" and then remove "c", "b" and then "a" if possible (directories not empty).  I do *not* want to unlink "basedir" or "overall".

filepath.HasPrefix would seem to be a good option but it's apparently deprecated: https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#HasPrefix

What I have now is:

```
p := THEPATH

// attempt to remove file and all parent directories up to the basedir
// FIXME: HasPrefix is apparently bad.. a better idea?
for filepath.HasPrefix(p, baseDir) {
    err := os.Remove(p)
    if err != nil {
        break
    }
    // climb up one
    p = filepath.Dir(p)
}
```

Looking for a succinct and reliable way that works on all Go supported platforms.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, path handling is rather complicated if you want to support all platforms that is supported by `golang`. Bellow is the solution that I've implemented so far (probably not the simplest one). Notes:

1. It supports generalized action rather than only `os.Remove`
2. Instead of string-based path comparison, function [`os.SameFile`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#SameFile) is used to test whether two files/directories are equal.
3. In the implementation, at first all candidate paths are visited and added to `visitedPaths` slice. Then, if no error occurs, an `action` is perform to each candidate path.

[The code](https://gist.github.com/ipsusila/7b1a7ae180f80b5db426cae8a51f465e):

```
package pathwalker

import (
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

type PathAction func(PathInfo) error
type PathInfo struct {
    FileInfo os.FileInfo
    FullPath string
}
type PathWalker struct {
    pathName     string
    basePath     string
    visitedPaths []PathInfo
    lastFi       os.FileInfo
}

//NewPathWalker creates PathWalker instance
func NewPathWalker(pathName, basePath string) *PathWalker {
    return &PathWalker{
        pathName: pathName,
        basePath: basePath,
    }
}

func (w *PathWalker) visit() (bool, error) {
    //Make sure path ends with separator
    basePath := filepath.Clean(w.basePath + string(filepath.Separator))
    baseInfo, err := os.Lstat(basePath)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    //clean path name
    fi, err := os.Lstat(w.pathName)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    } else if fi.IsDir() {
        //When pathname is a directory, remove latest separator
        sep := string(filepath.Separator)
        cleanPath := filepath.Clean(w.pathName + sep)
        w.pathName = strings.TrimRight(cleanPath, sep)
    } else {
        w.pathName = filepath.Clean(w.pathName)
    }
    return w.doVisit(w.pathName, baseInfo)
}

//visit path recursively
func (w *PathWalker) doVisit(pathName string, baseInfo os.FileInfo) (bool, error) {
    //Get file info
    fi, err := os.Lstat(pathName)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    //Stop when basePath equal to pathName
    if os.SameFile(fi, baseInfo) {
        return true, nil
    }

    //Top directory reached, but does not match baseInfo
    if w.lastFi != nil && os.SameFile(w.lastFi, fi) {
        return false, nil
    }
    w.lastFi = fi

    //Append to visited path list
    w.visitedPaths = append(w.visitedPaths, PathInfo{fi, pathName})

    //Move to upper path
    up := filepath.Dir(pathName)
    if up == "." {
        return false, nil
    }

    //Visit upper directory
    return w.doVisit(up, baseInfo)
}

//Walk perform action then return number of proceed paths and error
func (w *PathWalker) Walk(act PathAction) (int, error) {
    n := 0
    ok, err := w.visit()
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    } else if ok && act != nil {
        for _, pi := range w.visitedPaths {
            err := act(pi)
            if err != nil {
                return n, err
            }
            n++
        }
    }
    return n, nil
}

//VisitedPaths return list of visited paths
func (w *PathWalker) VisitedPaths() []PathInfo {
    return w.visitedPaths
}
```

Then if you want to remove file and parent directory under `basePath`, you can do:

```
func remove(pathName, basePath string) {
    act := func(p pathwalker.PathInfo) error {
        if p.FileInfo.IsDir() {
            fmt.Printf("  Removing directory=%s\n", p.FullPath)
            return os.Remove(p.FullPath)
        }

        fmt.Printf("  Removing file=%s\n", p.FullPath)
        return os.Remove(p.FullPath)
    }

    pw := pathwalker.NewPathWalker(pathName, basePath)
    n, err := pw.Walk(act)
    fmt.Printf("Removed: %d/%d, err=%v\n", n, len(pw.VisitedPaths()), err)
}
```

If you just want to test whether a path is inside another path, you can do:

```
n, err := pathwalker.NewPathWalker(fileName, basePath).Walk(nil)
if n > 0 && err != nil {
    //is inside another path
}
```

Comment: os.SameFile seems like exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks for the working code - I'm not sure I need something that sophisticated but this looks like a good approach nonetheless.